# Laravel 9 replies "Vite manifest not found" on production server

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

When I deploy a Laravel 9 project to production, Laravel replies:

> Spatie\LaravelIgnition\Exceptions\ViewException: Vite manifest not found at: /var/www/.../public/build/manifest.json in file /var/www/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Vite.php on line 139

It turns out the files in /public/build folder are not committed in the git repository, thus missing on production server.

Should I?

1. Install `npm` on production server and run `npm run build` to generate the manifest  files, or
2. Include the manifest files (e.g. manifest.json) of `/public/build` folder into my repository and pull them in production server ...

Comment: run `npm run build`

Comment: Yes, run npm run build and commit the compiled assets into the repo, OR build the assets on the production server.  I prefer to create the assets locally. Make sure your production server does not contain the `hot` folder

Comment: a long time has passed since this question, but i'm in the same situation. This sounds strange to me...

Comment: Seems stressful, but don't forget to add your production server. It is usually fine on dev until you push to production.

Answer (score 2):

You can add buildpacks (scripts that are run when your app is deployed. They are used to install dependencies for your app and configure your environment) on Heroku which will allow you to run npm. Well, easy does it on Heroku.

But if you happen to be on Fortrabbit, where you can't run `npm` or `vite` in ssh. The simplest way is to build your assets locally (`npm run build` or `vite build`) and push them to production.

Make sure you comment the `public/build` folder in .gitignore before pushing it to production. This might work for a lot (almost) of servers including Heroku without adding buildpacks.

Should this fail, make sure your APP_ENV is set to production `APP_ENV=production` or anything else except local as the documentation of vite states.